# How to save shadow catcher image as png?

Tags: image, shadowcatcher

I am brand new to Blender and 3D modeling and I know nothing at all about rendering. I make meshes for game assets that are just exported as objs, but I'd like to let Blender draw shadows for me onto a plane so I can use that image as part of a texture in game. I found out how to make a shadow catcher and I got a shadow, and I found a setting in output properties to save it as png, but I can't figure out how to actually save it. Tutorials skip from output settings to "put the image in Photoshop." Can I save as an image without learning all about rendering/Cycles/Eevee/allthethingsI'mnotreadyfor OR can someone give me a few simple instructions that would let me do it. Otherwise, I'm taking a screen shot of a shadow catcher which I'm sure must be a really dumb way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cycles to bake the shadow into a texture file. To do so, create a shadow catcher, you can do this by clicking the object properties button after selecting your plane. (It's the orange square) Then once it's a shadow catcher, and you have set up the lights to get the shadow you want, go to render settings, open bake, and select shadow. Now open the material you are using for your shadow catcher and add an image texture node. Press the create new button, choose your resolution and name. Then select it in the node editor. Now just click bake. [image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had to look up quite a few things to get this to work, but I have managed it. Thank you very much. The pictures helped a lot! I appreciate your time very much.